# Is it possible to oxidize ether to ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, esters

Is it possible to synthesize an ester from an ether in a single step? For example if I had an ether $\ce{(R-CH2-OR')}$, can I oxidize it so it will be an ester $\ce{(R-CO-OR')}$.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible.  One reagent to do so is acidic bromate salts.  [This paper](https://www.thevespiary.org/rhodium/Rhodium/pdf/thf2gbl.pdf) discusses a number of optimizations and characterizations of the bromate-powered ether oxidation reaction.

$$\ce{R-CH2-O-CH2-R + BrO3- ->[H+][H2O; {r.t.}] R-CO-O-CH2-R + Br^-}$$

Hydrolysis of the formed ester leads to an undesired byproduct: the free acid $\ce{RCOOH}$.  In addition to that byproduct, overoxidation of the substrate can also happen, leading to anhydrides or even $\ce{CO2}$.

There may well be plenty of other oxidants and catalysts than can achieve the same reaction, but I thought this one was notable because it works in water at room temperature.  Yield depends strongly on reaction conditions and the vagaries of the particular substrates you use, though.